# Override user edit page title

Tags: users, hooks

By default, the user form title is the user's username which looks a little ugly if you're using the [email registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration) module. In Drupal 7 I used to solve this problem using the [title override](https://www.drupal.org/project/title_override) module which is not ported do Drupal 8.

I would like to change the user form title to "Login details". Is this possible using a hook? If so: how do I do this?

Comment: This doesnt allow dynamic information e.g. node title, node type - unless you use global functions for pulling the node from the url rather than as a parameter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The title override module utilizes [`drupal_set_title()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7.x) to do this in Drupal 7. This function is [deprecated](https://www.drupal.org/node/2067859) in Drupal 8. The D8 equivalent here is to alter the `_title_callback` for the `entity.user.edit_form` route.

This is done by using an event subscriber to alter the `RoutingEvents::ALTER` event. This can be done through a custom module that:

- Registering a new service class in **mymodule.services.yml** that is tagged with `event_subscriber` (see d.o. [documentation example](https://www.drupal.org/node/2187643)).
- Defining the new service class to extend `RouteSubscriberBase` (see d.o. [documentation example](https://www.drupal.org/node/2187643)).
- Implementing the `alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)` method within the service class to alter the `entity.user.edit_form` route (see example below).
- A class/method that defines the title callback (see [`UserController::userTitle()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!src!Controller!UserController.php/function/UserController%3A%3AuserTitle/8.2.x) as an example).

Within your route subscriber class:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    // Retrieve the user edit form route.
    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.user.edit_form')) {
      // Your module will need a controller class/method defined in
      // src/Controller/CustomUserController::userTitle
      // see core/modules/user/src/Controller/UserController.php to see how this
      // is implemented by default
      $route->setDefault('_title_callback','Drupal\mymodule\Controller\CustomUserController::userTitle');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 8 you can hide the title block :

```
/admin/structure/block/manage/pagetitle
```

for the :

```
user/* pages
```

Then create a block that display what you want for the

```
user/* pages
```

.

It can also be dynamic if you create a view block with a contextual view displaying other user fields.

Comment: This solution is incomplete as the title in html header and in breadcrumb remain the inchanged